# Render metal signs from svg files

Tags: rendering, import, workflow, svg

I have 300 signs exported as a 2D svg file.
I would like to build a scene in Blender and exchange the SVG in the background. Maybe build a script that change the SVG and than renders the scene with the new sign. So I can let the PC render for a day and I have every sign as a picture.

Do someone know a workflow?

Comment: Do you know your svgs import properly? if so then yes not hard to script changing them out.

Comment: svg files can be imported to create curve objects, they don't work as image textures. See [this daily tip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJeipIO0wcw) showing to use save as from Illustrator and enable Presentation Attributes to be able to import svg files with colours.